# Escape special characters in image link

Tags: plugins, php

I am importing the images from XML using a plugin, it truncates the image link while importing. Some symbols are causing the images not to show in the posts. [This is the image link](http://crm.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1371&l_id=1008909&aid=5649&id=13941113029948883&wmt=1391509690&image=06_03_2014-17_11_58-1371-583876a908421c4b4cc3105051056bb5.jpg). 
What it shows is mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/watermark.jpeg
I need a php function which escapes the special characters in a URL. (Wordpress Plugin Name: WP-ALLIMPORT)

Comment: If you don't know the answer, stop giving downvotes to people. Its not a plugin issue. I am asking for a php function which can escape the special characters.

Comment: You might have to extract the link, run esc_url on that, and then rebuild the link.

Answer (score 1):

Because based on your description, I am not sure what is your purpose doing the escape.

If you want to escape the URL, you might consider using Wordpress internal [esc_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) function

If you want to do some more low level control with PHP native function, you may consider [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and you might have to manually urldecode() it in some cases depending on your purpose